# Sympy notation for power

Tags: sympy, notation

I am using `str` function to convert a sympy tree expression to an infix math string.  IThis works fine, except in the case when I convert a expression with a "power" (exponentiation); for example:

```
a = Symbol('a')

res = str(a**2)

print(res)
# a**2
```

Is there any way to convert a sympy tree expression to a standard infix math string form; i.e. `a^2` instead of `a**2`?

Comment: The `latex` display may allow this.  `**` is Python's standard operator for power.  `^` is bitwise xor.

Comment: Yes, I know that `^` is bitwise xor, but i want to convert sympy tree to string with `^` as power. For example reverse operation (convertion from str to sympy tree allows using `^` as a power)...